# Using “rivetted” (double t) is correct?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I am going through the following sentence.

> I looked up at my boss and his eyes were rivetted on me

google search auto corrects it to riveted. One of the meaning to rivet from Oxford is

> direct (one’s eyes or attention) intently

1. rivetted (using double t - tt) is incorrect?
2. In the above sentence what meaning best suits for rivetted?

Comment: The single 't' is correct because in this case, doubling of the consonant is determined by stress; when the last syllable (having the 't') is stressed, the 't' gets doubled, otherwise it remains single.

Comment: @Decapitated Soul thanks for explanation of why riveted is correct

Comment: A rivet affixes two metals together. Eyes riveted means they were fixed on something powerfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* lists both: **riveted, rivetted**.  But it seems in both US and UK, **riveted** is currently the more common.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riveted%2Crivetted&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3):
[image: X]

"direct (one’s eyes or attention) intently" matches the quotation given.

Comment: thanks for Ngram. Before -1835 rivetted was used mostly as per Ngram. I will use riveted while writing.

Comment: I note that Shakespeare used the single-t version, despite being before 1835.

Comment: Shakespeare is great no doubt. For this question GEdgar(you) for providing Ngram  and Decapitated Soul for providing the reason of Why riveted is correct are more than that to me.

Answer (score 5):

It should be **riveted** to be correct.

The rule for doubling a trailing T is when it's stressed. For example:

- *targeted* - pronounced as *TAR-ge-tid*, same for *targeting* (*marketed*, *marketing*)
- *regretted* - pronounced as *ri-GRE-tid*, same for *regretting* (*admitted*, *admitting* and for all single-syllable words like *chat*, *plot*, *put*, *sit* etc.)

Given **rivet** is pronounced as **RI-vit** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rivet#English)), *riveted* should not have double T. I would've spoken *ri-VE-tid* had I seen *rivetted*.

P.S. The same rule applies to a wide range of words ending in *vowel + consonant*, like *cap*, *repel*, *rob*, *blur*, etc.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how "rivetted"  commands a different pronunciation (ri•VET•id) and changes the meaning, as in to be "vetted" again.